# Android Library have a context?

Tags: android, database, android-library, realm

Is it possible for an Android Library to have its own context? The reason I ask is because I am using an Android Library that is used by multiple applications(APKs) and to store something in the database, it needs a context. If the Android Library can have it's own context, the Android Library can view all the data stored by the different applications.

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a database stored in a shared location, though be *very* careful only one client has it open at a time.  Or you can have an apk which functions as a repository for others, which share data with it via a mechanism such as a content provider.  Or you can do your storage in the cloud and have each apk interact with it via usual mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible for android library to have it's own context.
As context is runtime property of application, hence application pass it's own context only when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible like Google play service,
But at that time library itself work as another application may be in background process.

And use of library will work as communication between two applications.